# Download Task StdOut Output From UI

Tags: databricks

Databricks provides convenient access to `stdout` and `stderr` log associated with each Task ID related for the stage:
[image: Spark UI screenshot]

The log is read from some location on the cluster (UI shows few hundreds of lines and allows loading more). Is there a way to download full log for selected task w/o many times clicking "load more" manually? I don't want to redirect the entire log into dbfs (it's mostly useless), just getting details on specific tasks could be helpful.

Comment: do you need logs for specific task, or all logs?

Comment: @AlexOtt only one or few specific tasks based on current performance. Trying to avoid storing all logs as they're quite extensive and I have limited use for them.